# Calculating the possibility of winning numbers

Tags: probability, combinatorics, combinations

I know that we can calculate the possibility of a winning number in a $6/49$ lotto game with this formula:

$$C(n,r)= {n!\over r!(n−r)!}= C(49,6)={49 \choose 6}=\frac{49!}{6!(49−6)!}= 13 983 816$$

I can say that the probability of winning $6$ numbers is $1 / 13983816$ according to the above formula. I would like to calculate the same ratio for $3$, $4$, and $5$ numbers. Here I am seeking a formula to do this.

My question is how can I calculate the total number of combinations of $5,4$ and $3$ winning numbers out of the $6$ winning numbers in all possibilities? Is there a similar formula for this? Thanks.

Comment: hypergeometric distribution?

Comment: I am sorry, I am not familiar with what you're suggesting.

Comment: I don't know whether "hypergeometric distribution" is a good hint here, but I do know that you can type it into Google and see.

Comment: Thanks Gerry, I did that. but I couldn't find what I seek.  Can this be done with a formula like this n!(r!(n−r)!) without doing additional calculations?

Comment: I thought this would be an easy question :)

Comment: The probability of correctly selecting all six numbers is $\frac{1}{\binom{49}{6}}$ since there is one way to select all six numbers and $\binom{49}{6}$ possible outcomes.  Are you asking for the probabilities of selecting exactly $3$, $4$, or $5$ winning numbers or the number of favorable cases?

Comment: yes. I can say that the probability of winning 6 numbers is 1 / 13983816 acc.to the above formula. I would like to calculate the same ratio for 3,4, and 5 numbers.  Here I am seeking a formula to do this.

Comment: I have edited your question to include the information you supplied in the comments to make the question clearer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The number of possible outcomes is
$$\binom{49}{6}$$
which is the number of ways to select a subset of six of the $49$ numbers.

The number of ways to select exactly $k$ winning numbers is the number of ways we can select $k$ of the six winning numbers and $6 - k$ of the $43$ other numbers in the draw, which is 
$$\binom{6}{k}\binom{43}{6 - k}$$
Hence, the probability of selecting exactly $k$ of the winning numbers is
$$\frac{\dbinom{6}{k}\dbinom{43}{6 - k}}{\dbinom{49}{6}}$$
In particular, the probability of selecting all six winning numbers is
$$\frac{\dbinom{6}{6}\dbinom{43}{0}}{\dbinom{49}{6}} = \frac{1}{\dbinom{49}{6}}$$
which makes sense since there is only one way to correctly select all six numbers.

For $k = 2$, we get 
$$\frac{\dbinom{6}{2}\dbinom{43}{4}}{\dbinom{49}{6}}$$
I will leave the calculations for $k = 0, 1, 3, 4, 5$ to you.

The events $k = 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6$ are mutually exclusive and exhaustive, so their probabilities should add up to $1$.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer and explanation. I am a not math geek. I will use it for an article I am preparing. I wanted to be sure of my results. Thanks!